# SlickUpload alternative

Tags: jquery, asp.net, slickupload

I used SlickUpload http://slickupload.com/ for many project and I buy a regular license for version 6.x a few months ago.
I'm terrified about knowing that after the acquisition is not well supported anymore...the new company is not clear about the future of the product.

Is a great problem for my users, they love the Slick interface:

> http://slickupload.com/demos

and I'm not able to find a good alternative to this simple and functional interface.
Does anyone use a multi upload asp.net/jQuery component like SlickUpload, with:

- drag e drop
- multi upload
- if supported html5 actions
- simple use...

If is not the right place to ask this I'll move my question.

EDIT: asp .net ajax licensed components (like SlickUpload) are good too

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using plupload with asp.net since 1yr and it's really awesome.It supports various fallbacks and you can check it here. http://www.plupload.com/ and it supports multiple selection with drag and drop too.